# How to pass directly a lambda where an interface is expected

Tags: lambda, kotlin

In Lwjgl there is a function such as:

```
public static void glDebugMessageCallback(
@Nullable @NativeType("GLDEBUGPROC") GLDebugMessageCallbackI callback, 
@NativeType("void const *") long userParam) {
    nglDebugMessageCallback(memAddressSafe(callback), userParam);
}
```

and in Kotlin I can call it directly in the following way:

```
glDebugMessageCallback({ _, _, _, _, _, message, _ -> Unit }, NULL)
```

Now, I'd like to overwrite this call omitting the last parameter.

But if I type:

```
fun glDebugMessageCallback(callback: GLDebugMessageCallbackI) {

}
```

Then the same call without `NULL`:

```
glDebugMessageCallback({ _, _, _, _, _, message, _ -> Unit })
```

will get a Type mismatch:

```
Required: GLDebugMessageCallbackI

Found: (???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???) → Unit
```

Why and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin supports [SAM conversion](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Introduction/SAM%20conversions/Task.kt) only for interop with Java. So either declare your convenience method in a Java class or declare a function type for your Kotlin function, delegating to the Java call.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some more information to the answer of Marko Topolnik, there is a possibility that SAM conversions for Kotlin interfaces will be supported in version 1.3 as an experimental feature. Possible syntax can look like this:

```
sam interface Callback {
    fun justSingleMethod(first: Int, second: Int): Boolean
}
```

And usage will be the same as with Java interfaces:

```
fun doSomethingWithCallback(callback: Callback) {
    ...
}

doSomethingWithCallback { first, second -> true }
```

P.S. Info is taken from the following presentation by Stanislav Erokhin (russian language) https://youtu.be/gwk4rdgr36E?t=56m54s

Comment: Hopefully they won't reserve another keyword just for this :)

Comment: Per presentation, `sam` isn't going to be new keyword. It will be "safe keyword" (same as `data`) and you still will be able to declare variable with name `sam`.